# Is the output "[object X]" guaranteed in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, standards

When you call `Object.prototype.toString.apply(object)` on some object, you get a string back in the form `[object X]` for some type name `X` (e.g. `Array`, `Function`, `Null`, `Boolean`, `Number`, and so on).

Is this behavior guaranteed by any ECMAScript standard? I know it is unspecified what the result is for a *host object*, but what about regular objects in the ECMA standard?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [ECMA 5.1 Specifications](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4.2),

> When the `toString` method is called, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. If the `this` value is `undefined`, return `"[object Undefined]"`.
> 2. If the `this` value is `null`, return `"[object Null]"`.
> 3. Let `O` be the result of calling `ToObject` passing the `this` value as the argument.
> 4. Let `class` be the value of the `[[Class]]` internal property of `O`.
> 5. Return the String value that is the result of concatenating the three Strings `"[object ", class, and "]"`.

Also [`[[Class]]`](http://es5.github.io/#x8.6.2) is defined as,

> A String value indicating a specification defined classification of objects.
>
> The value of the `[[Class]]` internal property is defined by this specification for every kind of built-in object. The value of the `[[Class]]` internal property of a host object may be any String value except one of `"Arguments", "Array", "Boolean", "Date", "Error", "Function", "JSON", "Math", "Number", "Object", "RegExp"`, and `"String"`. The value of a `[[Class]]` internal property is used internally to distinguish different kinds of objects. Note that this specification does not provide any means for a program to access that value except through `Object.prototype.toString` (see 15.2.4.2).

Comment: Further, [§8.6.2](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2) says that host objects **must** implement a `[[Class]]` internal property, but the value is implementation dependent. Hence `Object.prototype.toString.call(DOMDivElement)` may return, say, `[Object HTMLDivElement]` in one browser (Safari) and `[object String] ` in another (IE 9).